# Can we use non-relative clauses as descriptive modifiers?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

In most grammar books, adjective/relative clauses are limited to specific constructs involving words such as 'that' or 'which' (as two of multiple examples):

> [1] The house **that I grew up in**

There are also examples of non-finite relative clauses, which use participles and infinitives:

> [2] The man **speaking on the stage**

> [3] The best time **to be alive**

However, there are other examples that are rarely spoken about. Consider these:

> [4] The time **before he found his calling**

> [5] The moment **after she discovered the truth**

> [6] Life **as we know it**

In the grammar resources that I have read, these types of clauses are always presented as adverbial, usually modifying a verb. Clearly, this is not their sole function. That being the case, are the examples above (4–6) correct? They are often used in both informal and formal English, so why do most resources neglect to mention them? If they are correct, would we class them as relative clauses?

Comment: Does the question you ask in the final paragraph refer to only your examples [4-6]?

Comment: I've posted an answer which deals with the analysis of all your examples.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it does. I should've specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *the house* [*that I grew up in*]
>
> [2] *the man* [*speaking on the stage*]
>
> [3] *the best time* [*to be alive*]
>
> [4] *the time* [*before he found his calling*]
>
> [5] *the moment* [*after she discovered the truth*]
>
> [6] *life* [*as we know it*]

These are a mixed bag of noun phrases containing various modifiers (bracketed), but only two of the modifiers are relative clauses:

[1] is a genuine relative construction, where the modifier is a relative clause modifying "house".

[2] The modifier here is a non-finite participial clause modifying "man". It is semantically similar to the relative clause in *the man who is*/*was speaking on the stage*.

[3] contains the infinitival relative clause "to be alive", which modifies "best time". It has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finites by "can/could" or "should", cf. *the best time that we could be alive*.

The modifiers in [4] - [6] are not clauses at all, but preposition phrases where [4-5] have a temporal meaning, [6] a comparative one.

Comment: Do you have any resources that explain how clauses can be objects of a preposition? It appears that my understanding is limited by thinking that objects can only be derivations of nouns (including gerunds). I imagine this is a result of relying on outdated grammar.

Comment: @MJAda Traditionally, _before_, _after_ and _as_ in those examples would be called **conjunctions** rather than prepositions. I understand that the class of _preposition_ has been considerable widened in recent work, particularly CGEL (which I'm still trying to decide whether I can afford to buy).

Comment: @MJAda My answer is based on modern grammar, which rejects the claim that prepositions can only take NPs as complement. The clauses in your examples are complements of the preceding preposition, but they are not objects as such -- the term 'object' is used for those complements with the form of an NP.

Comment: @BillJ In that case, what distinguishes these prepositions from regular conjunctions? Is it the fact that they are descriptive but not relative clauses?

Comment: @MJAda "Before", "after" and "as" are clearly prepositions in "I met him the day [before yesterday]"/ "I saw her [after the accident]" /  "I regard her [as a friend]", where they have NP object complements. Modern grammar expands the classification to include other kinds of complement such as clauses. In other words, it's just a matter of complementation.

Comment: @BillJ Is the best way to check to simply replace a clause with a NP? For example, 'although' cannot take a NP as a complement, so we know that it's not a preposition; however, as you mentioned, 'before' and 'after' can.